# Solving a system of 2nd order differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the

$\vec{x}''= \begin{bmatrix}-48 & 16\\32 & -32\end{bmatrix}\vec{x}$

I know how to solve this as a first order equation...Am I to take eigenvalues here? I tried visualizing them individually as second order equations but this confused me.

Comment: I found them here:

For $\lambda = -4$
\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\1\end{bmatrix}

For $\lambda = -1$
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\2\end{bmatrix}

Comment: You can diagonalize the matrix, solve the two equations of the diagonalized matrix independently and then find the solution of the original system by moving back to the standard basis using the eigenvectors of the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

From the matrix system, you can get a system of equations:
$$x_1''=-48x_1+16x_2$$$$x_2''=32x_1-32x_2$$
We can turn it into:$$(x_1''+48x_1)-16x_2=0$$$$-32x_1+(x_2''+32x_2)=0$$
which is then (using basic definition for differential equations) $$(D^2+48)x_1-16x_2=0$$$$-32x_1+(D^2+32)x_2=0$$
Multiply the first equation by $D^2+32$ and multiply the second equation by 16, we get:
$$(D^2+48)(D^2+32)x_1-16(D^2+32)x_2=0$$$$-32(16)x_1+(D^2+32)(16)x_2$$
Add them together, the equation we get is $$(D^4+80D^2+1024)x_1=0$$
From here you can factor out D and get the general solution for $x_1$, then plug the value back into the original equation to get $x_2$

Comment: Did you mean to have $x_1$ outside of the parentheses on your 5th line?

Comment: Honestly I don't know if I really understand what's going on here. I factored out $D^2$ and got

$[D^2(D^2+80)+1024]x_1 = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Using the "Ansatz" $x(t)=e^{\lambda t}(x_1,x_2)^T$ with $x_1$, $x_2$, and $\lambda$ yet to be determined we obtain the condition
$$x''(t)-Ax(t)=e^{\lambda t}\bigl((48+\lambda^2) x_1-16x_2, -32x_1+(32+\lambda^2)x_2\bigr)^T\equiv0\ .$$
This only admits a solution with $(x_1,x_2)\ne(0,0)$ if $\lambda$ solves the characteristic equation
$$\lambda^4+80\lambda^2+1024=0\ .\tag{1}$$
Fortunately we obtain four different solutions of $(1)$, namely $\pm4i$ and $\pm8i$. In order to obtain real solutions we therefore refine our "Ansatz" and write $x(t)=\cos(4t)(a_1,a_2)^T$. We then obtain the condition
$$x''(t)-Ax(t)=16\bigl(2a_1-a_2,-2a_1+a_2)^T\cos(4t)\equiv0\ ,$$
which is fulfilled when $a_2=2a_1$. It is easily seen that we obtain the same equation for $\sin(4t)$, so that we now have a two-dimensional space of solutions given by
$$x(t)=\bigl(a\cos(4t)+b\sin(4t)\bigr)(1,2)^T\ .$$
Now do the same  with $\cos(8t)$, resp., $\sin(8t)$, and obtain a second two-dimensional space of solutions in the form
$$x(t)=\bigl(c\cos(8t)+d\sin(8t)\bigr)(1,-1)^T\ .$$

Comment: I want to be able to express this as a system of two equations, but how can I do this when I have two $2 \times 1$ eigenvectors?

Comment: This  route is described in the comment of  Constantinos Vrohidis.